# ContextErrorException Notice: Undefined offset: 1 prestashop 1.7

Tags: ios

i have a delivery module that works perfectly on prestashop 1.5, when migrating to prestashop 1.7 i encountered the following problem, i'm new to prestashop but i think the problem comes from this line " $horaire=  explode('|', $select_day[1]);".

```
 public function hookDisplayCarrierExtraContent($params)
    {
          
        $jours = array();
        $stores= Store::getStores(Context::getContext()->language->id);
        $stores_datas=array(); 
         
        for($i = 0; $i<count($stores); $i++) 
        {
            $stores[$i]['name']    = str_replace(["'", '"'],"&#39;",$stores[$i]['name']);
            $stores[$i]['address1']= str_replace("'","&#39;",$stores[$i]['address1']);
            $stores[$i]['address2']= str_replace("'","&#39;",$stores[$i]['address2']);
            $stores[$i]['hours']    = str_replace(["'", "[", "]", '"'],"",$stores[$i]['hours']);

            $stores[$i]['hours'] = explode(',' ,$stores[$i]['hours'] );         

            $stores[$i]['note']    = str_replace("'","&#39;",$stores[$i]['note']);
            $stores_datas[$stores[$i]['id_store']] = $stores[$i];
            $stores_datas[$stores[$i]['id_store']]['has_store_picture'] = file_exists(_PS_STORE_IMG_DIR_.(int)($stores[$i]['id_store']).'.jpg');
            
            $stores_datas[$stores[$i]['id_store']]['hours'] = $stores[$i]['hours'];  
            $stores_datas[$stores[$i]['id_store']]['working_days_hours']=$this->_getStoreWorkingHours($stores[$i]);
            /*dump($this->_getStoreWorkingHours($stores[$i]));die;*/
            if (is_array($this->_getStoreWorkingHours($stores[$i])) || is_object($this->_getStoreWorkingHours($stores[$i])))
            {
            foreach ($this->_getStoreWorkingHours($stores[$i]) as $jour) 
            {
                $jours[$jour['id']] = $jour['day'];
            }
            }
        }
        //extract selecte day from the selected address.
        // the date and hours are stored in "other" field of Address as a string.
        $cart=$params['cart'];
        ksort($jours);
        // Get the selected adress form cart.
   
        $selected_adress=new Address($cart->id_address_delivery);
        //extract day.
        $select_day= explode(')',$selected_adress->other);
        $horaire=  explode('|', $select_day[1]); ------preblem is here 
        $jour=$horaire[0];
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'stores' => json_encode($stores_datas),
            'carrier' => (int)Configuration::get('AVAILABLE_STORE_DELIVERY_CARRIER'),
            'map' => Configuration::get('AVAILABLE_STORE_DELIVERY_DISPLAY_MAP'),
            'address_id' =>$selected_adress->alias,
            'jour_id'=> $this->getDateWeek($horaire[0]),
            'jours' => $jours,
            'json'=> serialize($stores_datas) 

        ));
     
        if(Configuration::get('AVAILABLE_STORE_DELIVERY_DISPLAY_MAP') == true) 
        {
            $this->context->smarty->assign('heightMap',Configuration::get('AVAILABLE_STORE_DELIVERY_HEIGHT_MAP'));
            $this->context->smarty->assign('widthMap',Configuration::get('AVAILABLE_STORE_DELIVERY_WIDTH_MAP'));
            $this->context->smarty->assign('defaultLat',(float)Configuration::get('PS_STORES_CENTER_LAT'));
            $this->context->smarty->assign('defaultLong', (float)Configuration::get('PS_STORES_CENTER_LONG'));
            $this->context->smarty->assign('logo_store', Configuration::get('PS_STORES_ICON'));
            $this->context->smarty->assign('hasStoreIcon', file_exists(_PS_IMG_DIR_.Configuration::get('PS_STORES_ICON')));
        }


        return $this->display(__FILE__,'availablestoredelivery.tpl');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is trying to getting data by exploding the “other” string field of address database object first by ) symbol, then by pipe symbol | without any consistency check , so have a look at your customer address “other” field content, maybe they weren’t properly migrated during the versione upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
the other field is already empty so no content since the previous version .... therefore no modification at the database level: /